# I wish to declare many named objects with attributes coming from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am new to classes and just trying to force it into my task to see if it will help me. I have declared a class named Client, with initial attributes being name and assets, which are names, not values.

I read data from a dataframe to aggregate the clients and assets into a dictionary, there the idea would be:

```
client_dict[client_1] = <list of assets that client 1 holds>

client_dict[client_2][asset_x] = <the price/value of client 2's holding in asset x>
```

I have this dictionary setup although my top line will actually pull the nested dictionary, so instead:

`client_dict[client_1] = <dictionary where keys are all the ***keys**** are the assets the values are the prices>`
*ok I think I just solved that problem by talking it out, thanks in advance

However I also which to pass the entire client dictionary into my Client class and have all of the clients accessible by their unique names. Everywhere I look, tutorials define the objects explicitly, one at a time. I have 50 clients with unique names, I want to pass them all and be able to access their attributes and eventually methods by this name. Without entering them one at a time. How!? I can pass the dictionary fine, but trying to call the client after (client_x.attribute) tells me that client_x is not defined.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not clear to me what advantages you would gain from defining classes over defining dicts. It is possible to have some sort of a base class with a basic set of attributes, and define new attributes dynamically (setattr, or overloading __getattribute__) but what would be the advantage over using an object with data in a dict? I sort-of feel we might not understand one another well enough. Also, playing with setattr, __getattribute__ is something you would not do if you are just starting with classes.

Comment: Thank you for your thought Petr.  I recognize I am likely making many inefficient moves. I have retrieved the original data from a sql query that normally goes into an excel book. It feels somewhat awkward working with this dataframe, as I need to link this up with many other tables. Working with dictionaries feels natural to me to not lose the linkages between the variables, and that I will turn it back into a dataframe once all the data is collected. So I figured because I am already working with dictionaries, it would be convenient to feed them into my Client class fcn this way.